# How do I access the contents of this list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, csv

I need to access the new information added to `data_list` in the `get_data_list` function within the second function which is `get_month_averages`, but when I try to do that, it says `data_list` is undefined. How do I do this?

```
import csv

def get_data_list(data_file):
    data_file = open("table.csv", "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
    return data_list

def get_month_averages(data_list):
    date_list = []
    vol_list = []
    adjclos_list = []
    for row in data_list:
        date_list.append(row[0])
        vol_list.append(row[5])
        adjclos_list.append(row[6])
        all_list = [date_list, vol_list, adjclos_list]
    return all_list
print (get_month_averages(data_list))
```

Comment: It's complaining about the bottom `print` line because you've never defined `data_list` when you pass it to `get_month averages`. You need a line before it (and outside the functions) like `data_list = get_data_list()`. Also the first line of your function should just be `def get_data_list():` because it doesn't need to take arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
import csv

def get_data_list():
    data_file = open("table.csv", "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
    return data_list

def get_month_averages(data_list):
    date_list = []
    vol_list = []
    adjclos_list = []
    for row in data_list:
        date_list.append(row[0])
        vol_list.append(row[5])
        adjclos_list.append(row[6])
        all_list = [date_list, vol_list, adjclos_list]
    return all_list

dList = get_data_list()
mAvg = get_month_averages(dList)
print mAvg
```